# How do I create multidimensional arrays in angular2

Tags: angular2-services

I'm creating a service of 'global' variables to import into other components (ie. make them available everywhere). This code works in old javascript:

```
sArrays = [];
sArrays[0] = [0,1,2,3];
sArrays[1] = [3,0,1,2];
sArrays[2] = [2,3,0,1];
sArrays[3] = [1,2,3,0];
```

but throws an error:

[ts] Duplicate identifier 'sArrays'. [ts] Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'sArrays' must be of type 'any[]', but here has type '[number, number, number, number]'. (property) GlobalsService.sArrays: any[]

in Typescript and I don't understand the error (aren't I creating a Type Array of a Type Array?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just be missing the var/let assignment for sArrays.

```
let sArrays = [];
```